# How to load zipped csv files in to hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I have bunch of csv files listed inside zipped file in hdfs. Is there any way to create a hive table above those with right data?

Note: data is quoted with " in csv file.

Comment: ZIP format is not a native Hadoop format. You'd be better off uncompressing or changing to BZIP2

Comment: As stated by @cricket_007 the **.zip** format is currently not supported by the Hadoop framework and it's a work [in-progress](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-210). So a work around would be to either have the files _uncompressed_ or have them converted to Hadoop supported compressed formats .bz2 .gz or .deflate...